# GameCenter Challenges do not work in Sandbox?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center

We have been trying to integrate GameCenter challenges into our latest release.  Everything else works just fine in the Sandbox, however, Challenges do not.

When we submit a challenge, the delegate returns that it was not sent and nothing shows up in the native GameCenter view controller.

Does anyone know if this is expected?  How should we test Challenge code if not in the sandbox?

**Extra Credit**  Has anyone seen documentation that is actually current on Challenges? Everything we have seen references old deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can work in the sandbox, but my experience is that you need two iOS devices (not the simulator) both logged in to separate GC accounts when testing them.  Do this and you will see the challenges appear fairly quickly, otherwise it's a bit random whether they will turn up at all.

Comment: Just to clarify, we are on iOS7.  Sadly, despite being on two different devices with different GC logins, we still don't see the challenges come across.

Comment: Unbelievable, just figured out the reason it wasn't working for us.  We were including a message.... setting that to nil and everything works on the device.  ARGH.  never mind that message is one of the parameters in the method call!